# How do I only undo pasted text in vim?

Tags: vim, osx

TL;DR; version - How do I undo text that was pasted in from my OS copy buffer without undoing other text that was typed in since I went into insert mode?

Longer description:

1. Put something in your OS copy buffer (e.g. highlight some text and do `Command-c` on Mac)
2. Go into insert mode in vim ( `i` )
3. Type something ( e.g. `asdf`)
4. Without exiting insert mode, paste from your copy buffer into vim ( `Command-v` on Mac)
5. Hit `escape`
6. Try to undo the paste ( `u` )

It undoes everything from the last time you went into insert mode. In otherwords, it clears out `asdf` plus all the text I pasted in.

How do I *just* undo the text that pasted in? Do I have to always go out of insert mode and back in before I paste text just to have the option to undo the pasted text?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is explicitly dropping out and back into insert mode before the paste. If you extend the paste commands, you can also automatically set an *undo point* before the paste:

```
" Any text fragment pasted in insert mode should be undone separately, without
" destroying what was typed before.
inoremap <C-R> <C-G>u<C-R>
```

The above is for the built-in `i_CTRL-R` command. I don't know how `Command-v` is implemented in MacVim, but prepending `<C-G>u` to the `:imap` command should achieve the same effect.

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks! I should probably stick with standard vim methods for pasting anyways.

Comment: Just adding this: `:h i_CTRL-G_u` (i.e., "break undo sequence, start new change" in insert mode).

Answer (score 2):

In MacVim, you need to unmap the `Edit > Paste` menu item in order to override the shortcut, then you can remap Cmd-V (`D-v` in MacVim parlance) to the appropriate command in each mode. I added this to my `~/.gvimrc` and now everything works wonderfully:

```
macmenu Edit.Paste key=<nop>
noremap <D-v> "*P
cnoremap <D-v> <C-r><C-o>*
inoremap <D-v> <C-g>u<C-r><C-o>*
```

The `<C-g>u` is necessary only in insert mode to fix the undo history; the `noremap` and `cnoremap` are simply to restore the default paste behavior in the normal and command modes.

Thanks to Ingo Karkat for pointing me in the right direction here.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the solution is you have to go to command mode(e.g. <kbd>Esc</kbd>) first and re-enter the insert mode, but it only works if I type manually but it seems "randomly" stop working if I test it in `~/.vimrc`. Google doesn't help at all.

I spends a lot of time try to fix this issue and I just figure out the reason in my case:

**Don't map the paste key same with the terminal existing paste key**

e.g. <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+V</kbd> will paste in my Konsole terminal, but if I assign this key `<C-S-v>` in `~/.vimrc`, the "undo for only single paste instead of multiple pastes" will not working.

In my case, I have to use `<C-v>` instead of `<C-S-v>`:

```
inoremap <C-v> <Esc>"+pi<Esc>i<Right><Right>
```

Your case may difference, but the point is same: don't assign the same paste key conflicts with existing terminal emulator key.

**I've 100% proved this conclusion by set my terminal paste key to <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd> and now `<C-v>` stop working but `<C-S-v>` working.**

Note also that the vim is too sensitive and strange. I figure out I have to use `i` and then 2 Right keys manually to make it works in the correct cursor position, that's means I have to put `i` and 2 Right keys in the `~/.vimrc` too. Your case might difference, but the point is same, ensure the keys+order in ~/.vimrc 100% match with what you type manually.